# Is "Milk and honey" a way to describe curvy women?

Tags: terminology

In Czech there is a term used for curvy women:

> krev a mlíko

"Krev a mlíko" means "blood and milk". In this term, "blood" is a reference to red cheeks on a girl (which was considered a sign of health) and "milk" was probably a reference to the fact that milk was considered a healthy part of the diet. It may have also been a euphemism for breasts.

Anyway, is there an equivalent term for a curvy woman in English? Is "Milk and honey" a way to describe curvy women or does it mean something different?

By *curvy*, I mean the classical hourglass shape — i.e. the right waist-to-hip ratio. 
Something like this:

[image: A picture of a woman with a curvy or hourglass figure.]

Comment: This might be a difficult question to answer, because most of the terms I can think of to describe the woman on the top could also be applied to the woman on the bottom. (One person's complimentary adjective is another person's euphemism.) The first few suggestions that came to my mind were _buxom, ample-figured_, and _Ruebenesque_. One could use _buxom_, I suppose, but you might need to rely on context to unequivocally ensure the right meaning comes across. But to answer your original question, no, you wouldn't use "milk and honey."

Comment: Doesn't everyone speaking English just say 'curvy'? It's understood that people don't mean *overweight*, or *unshapely* when using 'curvy'.

Comment: What's wrong with _hourglass figure_? That you can't eat glass? You want something edible, obviously, such like Yasmin Alibhai-Brown used in The Independent: "Five years ago, Kareena Kapoor, a top young actress in Bollywood, was a typical Punjabi girl, buxom and shapely, luscious like sweet kulfi ice-cream. Today she is svelte and sinewy enough to jog on the streets of LA and wear the tightest of designer jeans."

Comment: "The pages of teenage and women’s magazines are rife with metaphors presenting women in the guise of edible substances (honey, pie, tart, peach)" [http://revistas.ucm.es/index.php/EIUC/article/download/EIUC0707110015A/7707](http://revistas.ucm.es/index.php/EIUC/article/download/EIUC0707110015A/7707)

Comment: "...creating homogeneity in the female group and, therefore, leaving little room for individuality. In fact, the media dictate who women are, for instead of portraying real women, the media construct socially accepted notions of what women should be like. In other words, these magazines do not mirror women’s concerns, interests or even women themselves, but rather, borrowing Gitlin’s metaphor, they become fun-house mirrors distorting reality."

Comment: 'Milk and honey' and 'blood and milk' are not used in English for body types. The first phrase is a sign of plenty referring to land or a nation and has no gender overtones. The second just sounds weird in English.

Comment: @mikhailcazi, I would have said rather the opposite: if you describe a woman being _curvy_, there is a very high probability that you are in fact euphemistically calling her obese.

Comment: Interestingly, the expression ‘milk and blood’ exists in Danish as well, though it means something different there: it refers to looking young and healthy. The milk there refers to smooth, white skin, while the blood refers to rosy cheeks or dark hair (or both). I wonder if the two expressions are related, or just happen to be the same by coincidence.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It's surprising, I've never come across a negative connotation to *curvy* before.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Curvy doesn't imply obese (*i.e.* with a BMI >30).  We call those women fat.  It implies slightly overweight but well-proportioned.  (BMI ~ 27.)  If you were not attracted to this shape, you'd probably call it chubby.

Comment: @David, note the key word _euphemistically_. You don't call a woman fat if you wish to sound polite, diplomatic, and inoffensive about it; nor so you call her chubby. I have heard _curvy_ used to imply actual obesity many times, just like with epithets as _big girl_ etc.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I guess.  But, it's more of a polite downgrade.  Like saying, "Eh, it's not *that* bad."  It's like how I describe myself as athletically built.  But, in reality, I am muscular, but slightly overweight.  (6' 220")  I would argue that curvy is a better fit for full-figured, rather than obese.  It's just that some people want to be polite and will downplay the obvious.

Comment: Why would this be downvoted?  It's a perfectly clear question.  Weird.

Answer (score 3):

Milk and honey refers more to the Hebrew Bible's description of Israel and it's agricultural fruitfulness.  "A land flowing with milk and honey."

The phrase has since been co-opted to mean any sort of paradise which is rife with nourishment.

If you were to really stretch the metaphor, you could use this to describe a curvaceous woman.  But, I don't think that many would get your drift straight off the bat.

But, as the other posters have pointed out, there are significantly more idiomatically appropriate choices that English speakers would understand at face value.

I will add a few:

*If you want to sound campy*:  **Va-va-va-voom**

*If you are referring to specifically her ample breasts*:  **Busty,**  **Stacked,**  **Buxom**

*If you are referring to her buttocks being shapely and large*:  **Booty-licious,**  **Baby Got Back**

*If you are trying not to get your face slapped:* **Full-figured**, **Curvaceous**,  **Well-Proportioned**

Answer (score 1):

**moderate**
[**shapely**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shapely?q=shapely): /ˈʃeɪpli/

> *adj* (especially of a woman or part of her body) having an attractive or well-proportioned shape: *however much she ate it made no difference to her shapely figure*

**impressive**
**[voluptuous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/voluptuous?q=voluptuous%20)**: /vəˈlʌptjʊəs/

> (of a woman) curvaceous and sexually attractive.

**No comment**
36-24-36

Answer (score 1):

The very simple answer is "no", you've just confused "milk and honey", which is unrelated to women's figures.

Great question.

If you mean the **"Marilyn Monroe"** type of figure, as in your photo (i.e.: a nice, lovely figure, NOT the 10-year-old-boy-like "waif" seen in advertising images of women since about 1990, due to the extreme predominance of homosexual men in the fashion advertising field) then **shapely** or **voluptuous** work well (today) as, sort of "positive euphemisms" for that figure.

The situation is quite confusing as the photo you show is - **today** - seen as "a bit fat".  (Again, that's because of the dominance of images of weird small-boy-like almost-women in advertising through the 90s.)  But in, say, the 1950s or earlier, nobody would even think of that person as fat, and art directors from that era would be confused what we are asking.

Comment: ‘Blood and milk’ or ‘milk and honey’ both sound like English ‘peaches and cream’ describing complexion, not shape. 

‘Blood and milk’ doesn’t work in English. It sounds like a Maasai or Klingon or Viking, perhaps, Janus warrior’s diet; nothing to do with beauty.

50 years ago ‘Curvacious’ or ‘curvy’ might have been entirely literal. Today they clearly do mean ‘overweight’ or even ‘obese’ at least often enough to be dangerous and no, you can’t safely call her ‘chubby’ or ‘cuddly’ or ‘bubbly’ or anything like that; not without souring the whole sundae.

Answer (score 1):

> - Is "Milk and honey" a way to describe curvy women or does it mean something different?

When used figuratively, the  phrase [‘land of milk and honey’](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/land-of-milk-and-honey) refers to the **fertility** and **abundance** of any land or nation, it was originally used in the Bible to describe Israel,  and is found in Leviticus 20:24, and Numbers 16:13, among several other references.

> But I have said unto you, you shall inherit their land, and I will give it unto you to possess it, a land that *flows with milk and honey*: I am the LORD your God, who has separated you from other people..
>
> Is it a small thing that you have brought us up out of a land that *flows with milk and honey*, to kill us in the wilderness, that you make yourself altogether a prince over us?

That imagery is especially fixed among American English speakers, it would be unthinkable for them to adopt  the [binomial pair](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/Binomial-term.htm) ‘milk and  honey’ for that of the undulating curves of a woman.

However, taken separately, the two terms could describe a person's character or physical appearance.

### Milk

William Shakespeare used the term  *milk* in Macbeth to represent the purity and goodness of a person, as in:

> 1. The [**milk of human kindness**](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/247200.html)

For William Wells Newell, the bosom and skin of a woman was compared to that of milk

> 2. Down she comes [**as white as milk**](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Journal_of_American_Folklore_vol._12.djvu/305),
>    A rose in her bosom, as soft as silk.

### Honey

> 1. [**sweet as honey**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sweet+as+honey)
>    *very sweet; charming.*

The nonreversible [word pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_twins_(linguistics)), *milk and honey*, is used metaphorically in the *Song of Solomon* 4:11 when the author compares the idyllic ingredients to the taste of a woman's mouth, thereby promising sweetness and fertility.

> Your lips drop sweetness as the honeycomb, my bride;
> [**milk and honey**](http://biblehub.com/songs/4-11.htm) are under your tongue.
> The fragrance of your garments is like the fragrance of Lebanon

The OP asked:

> - Anyway, is there an equivalent term for a curvy woman in English?

There are a number of suitable expressions which I have listed. Apologies to those users who already suggested a few of these.

```
- busty                      - o̶p̶u̶l̶e̶n̶t̶ [ambiguous]       - pneumatic 
- buxom                      - Rubenesque                - well-endowed 
- curvaceous                 - shapely                   - well proportioned
- curvy                      - smoking hot [equivocal]   - zaftig
- full-figured               - thick
- an hourglass figure        - voluptuous
```

For a more modern approach, there's the adjective  ***thick*** which is also used to describe a woman who has, let's say, some extra flesh on her bones, but is not the F-word (i.e. *fat*). Not to be confused with the derogatory meaning [**4**. *Of low intelligence; stupid*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thick), this sense of *thick* is described on Urban Dictionary as referring to:

> A woman with a perfect body, filled-in in places that are, by nature, designed to attract the opposite sex, such as the thighs, the hips, the breasts, and the most lovely part of all, the booty.
>
> <sub>*[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=thick)* 2nd definition; October 21, 2004; 4,601 ‘thumbs up’.</sub>

### The hourglass shape

The 1920s saw the emergence of the young slim boyish look, women who followed this look were called *[flappers](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/arts-culture/the-history-of-the-flapper-part-3-the-rectangular-silhouette-20328818/)* but as the century progressed, the ideal size of both the breasts and buttocks increased. From the 1950s to 1960 women's breasts became larger and distinctively pointier due to the popularity of the bullet bra. This accentuated the waist to hip ratio, and led to the comeback of  19th century craze of corsets and girdles, as can be seen on the lovely Sophia Loren in the OP's post. The image below shows the "ideal" hourglass shape and an exaggerated *[wasp waist](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/wasp-waist)* that nevertheless remained popular until the  the [Twiggy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twiggy)  look dominated the covers of fashion magazines from the mid-sixties.

[image]

Comment: Like _thick_, I would advise caution if using _opulent_ or _smoking (hot)_ since they have other meanings that will quite likely prevail over the intended one here. _Opulent_, when used to describe people, tend to describe people who are **rich**, rather than curvy women; and _smoking (hot)_ just means ‘sexually [and subjectively] attractive’, regardless of body type. So it would be perfectly conceivable, for example, for someone to describe Paris Hilton as opulent and smoking hot, but thick, despite the fact that body-type-wise she’s a stick figure.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet hello, the adjective *opulent* is inappropriate in this case, I must have been mixing it up with Italian *opulenza* (n) http://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Italiano/parola/O/opulenza.aspx?query=opulenza and [*opolenta*](http://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Italiano/parola/O/opulento.aspx?query=opulento) (fem. adj)

Comment: If used to refer to the curves of the body, I’d say it can work quite well—just not if referring to the person herself. You could describe someone as having opulent curves and be fine… though I think perhaps I’d be quite likely to interpret that as being more of a Venus of Willendorf than a Venus of Milo.

Comment: As for smoking [hot], it's usually related to womanly figures, not androgynous body types, but I get your point, it's not a compliment exclusive to Sophia Loren or Monica Bellucci whose figures are hourglass shaped. .

Comment: My main association with “smoking!” (and probably at least some others’ as well) is Jim Carrey in _The Mask_ where he says it quite a lot of Cameron Diaz. Now I would definitely not think of her as androgynous, but there ain’t much flesh on them bones either. ;-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet thanks for correcting the typo, I'm still pondering whether to delete *opulent*, a person who describes a woman as having an opulent body would probably be misunderstood. *Smoking* shall remain, mainly because I like it, if someone said Salma Hayek is smoking hot, I don't think anybody would object or not know "why"☺

Comment: Again, just for the sake of clarity, the use of 'smoking hot' is completely irrelevant to a curvaceous body, and therefore doesn't belong on the list.

Comment: @BrianMitchell And just to reiterate, saying that Sofia Loren was smoking hot seems to me perfectly legitimate. "Smoking hot" is used for sexually attractive women, and women with curves are more likely to be "hot" than flat chested ones :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Are ALL curvaceous women 'smoking hot'?  Are ALL 'smoking hot' women curvaceous?   If not, then no, curvaceous and smoking hot are not synonyms.

Comment: @BrianMitchell fine. You are right. Now go to David M and tell him that slim- hipped long-legged beauties can also be *Va-va-va-voom*.

Comment: haha @Mari-LouA, I'm afraid va-va-voom is outside of my lexicon.  I see it's based on cars, and comes from the 50's,  which only leads me to want to point out that we no longer prefer our cars with exaggerated curves either ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of expressions that might be used, but among the more printable ones I would commend the top-most figure as 'CURVACEOUS'.

> **curvaceous**
>   (especially of a woman or a woman's figure) having an attractively curved shape
>   *‘Tobias's eyes followed the curvaceous waitress with black hair and dark skin before returning to Mia, who was looking at the menu.’*
>   <sub>[Oxford *Living* Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/curvaceous)</sub>